# ASP.NET Core Identity Extend Not Saving

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm attempting to extend the ASP.NET Identity. I feel like I have most of the parts. The model and user objects all properly populate. However, when I check the database for the new record inserted via the CreateAsync function, the new fields are all NULL. What am I missing?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName
                , Organization = model.Organization };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id.ToString(), code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }



        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            // Signin settings
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName;

    public String LastName;

    public String Organization;
}
```

Comment: This is either a typo or isn't your whole method.

Comment: I've updated the original post with more code. I didn't think it was originally relevant... but I probably should have just done so from the get go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use auto-implemented properties in your `ApplicationUser` class instead of just using public fields. That might be the problem.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String Organization { get; set; }
}
```